# "A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type" only when using generic type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type guard for narrowing Partial to non-Partial. For some reason I cannot compile it when it's generic, but it works without the generic type.

Suppose there's following setup:

```js
type Foo = {
  a: number
  b?: string
  c: string
}

let partialFoo: Partial<Foo> = {}

const doSomething = (foo: Foo) => {}
```

Meanwhile, somewhere else, I want to call function `doSomething(..)` with argument `partialFoo` while knowing `partialFoo` is assignable to `Foo` and I want to make compiler believe me. Normally it would complain about `Argument of type 'Partial<Foo>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo'`, so I created a type guard in order to narrow the type of variable `partialFoo`.

```js
type DefinedProp<T, TProp extends keyof T> = { [P in TProp]-?: T[P] } & Omit<T, TProp>

const hasDefinedProps = <TProp extends keyof Partial<Foo>>(
  partial: Partial<Foo>,
  propNames: TProp[]
): partial is DefinedProp<Partial<Foo>, TProp> => {
  return propNames.every(x => partial[x] !== undefined)
}

if(!hasDefinedProps(partialFoo,['a','c']))
{
  throw new Error('props must be defined here')
}

doSomething(partialFoo) // fine, because partialFoo is DefinedProp<Partial<Foo>, 'a' | 'c'>, which is same as type { a: number, b?: string, c: string }
```

**EDIT 1:** (Added missing type DefinedProp<..> above)

The problem happens, when I want to get rid of dependency `Foo` in `hasDefinedProps` by making it more generic:

```js
const hasDefinedProps = <T, TProp extends keyof T>(
  partial: T,
  propNames: TProp[]
): partial is DefinedProp<T, TProp> => { // Error: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  return propNames.every(x => partial[x] !== undefined)
}
```

This fails to compile saying **A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.**

**EDIT 2:**
[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKBDAXFAOwFcBbAIwgCdMoyB+fAZ2EoEsCBzGgYyZfa4BfdOgA2EYFDDZKwVtlHw4+AAoy5CgDxKAfMjTD03OAWZQAJnADKcEhIAWA-QAoAZgnxKAlMj2pDoJBQACIQruwQ5iqUcGCaACoANFDx0bFQEAAewBAE5oxQANYQIHCuKXooqFAA2ipQ7ClpYAC6ALQMKXUtUIJQAGRQAPIkrMAJyakxYDoixqaS9tiMoeEEkc0FKAnNGdm5+UUlZVBqsvKi2gg6Os400ucKquoXV3A6iffTAHLYdoz4KaxGotdBefAPDSiBoFVYRKLTTRnKFvD5NaaVPw0SgSIiUAhSH5-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-yAs0IJghCDovhJGyImpQIzPS1QjoWxb4F2UDwYSkS8dgORRnB4DQFWNawUJHAENgFHQMAiBjAUDzEn2YX+RFpLYri+KEhZxJkpS1K0vSYbMmyHJQFydZXuYbZAA)

Any helps would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WPZjKN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz . I added the missing type and link to TypeScript playground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition for `DefinedProp` was not in the question, so I used this one:

```
type DefinedProp<T, Key extends keyof T> = T & Required<Pick<T, Key>>
```

after which `hasDefinedProps` type checks and works as expected:

```
const test = (foo: Foo) => {
  if (hasDefinedProps(foo, [ 'b'])) {
    const t = foo.b // string
  } else {
    const t = foo.b // string | undefined
  }
}
```

So I guess the problem was in the definition of `DefinedProp`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFKBDAXFAOwFcBbAIwgCdMoyB%20fAZ2EoEsCBzGgYyZfa4BfdOlCQoAEQgAzdhAAmABUpwwAHgAqAGigBpCCCgQAHsAgF5jKAGsDcaVA0A%20ZI6gAyKACUIARyKslApqiqzc1po6%20iBOTiIANhDAUGDYlMCs2PHwcPiKaRlZajkuKKjC6NxwBMxQ8nAAynAkSQAWAq4AFNII%20DkAlMgu5SJVNcmt2IxSsgQKyqpWKJGOC2BGpuaWNnYOzp00qemZ8fjahypgAHLYLYxnawDaALro-fhHhfFQrFYzckpLisNGtSsMaEFgERKAQUpcbncAHQQABuVBAnWMQxSBROj2MzygAEIkCgiBYZAD%20ugKmNamZaihur1YAhBkhwVhWA5OpNppS5oDFsy4DpHlAAORkCXPfqDDBYLB05LAACMrh6cER2BoWAA9HrFVAAHp0XVQZVQYAAJg1CERZHNBqNpvNluAAGY7VruE7DYrXVhBEZ4oxoArFe71ShNdq-S6zUb3baY-bHUbnQHE5HqvSvamffGszRhIIgA)

**Update:**

The definition of `DefinedProp` makes the question more interesting. As seen above, we can declare a type predicate

```
hasDefinedProps: <T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, keys: K[]) => o is DefinedProp<T, K>
```

with

```
type DefinedProp<T, K extends keyof T> = T & Required<Pick<T, K>>
```

In this type, `T` provides the properties for keys not in `K`, and overlapping optional properties with keys in `K` are harmless as they become required by intersecting with `Required<Pick<T, K>>` anyway.

The question is why a very similar type that omits the required properties:

```
type DefinedPropO<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Required<Pick<T, K>>
```

yields a type error:

```
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'DefinedPropO<T, K>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'DefinedPropO<T, K>'.(2677)
```

The first part of the error basically means that a type predicate cannot state that the parameter is something is cannot be according to its type. The second part often indicates there's an issue with unions.

It turns out `DefinedPropO` has some issues with unions. For example:

```
Type Test = DefinedPropO<{a:0, b?:0} | {a:1, b?: 1}, 'b'> // {a: 0 | 1, b: 0 | 1}
```

This type will allow `{a:0, b:1}`, which is not assignable to `{a:0, b?:0} | {a:1, b?: 1}`.

The reason why the value types are unions has to do with the fact that both `Pick` and `Omit` are non-homomorphic mapped types, which don't distribute over unions.

The interesting bit is that `DefinedProp` without `Omit` works fine, even though it also uses `Pick`. Why this happens becomes clear by manually evaluating the type:

```
type Test = DefinedProp<{a:0, b?:0} | {a:1, b?: 1}, 'b'>> // {a:0, b:0} | {a:1, b:1}
  ->        ({a:0, b?:0} | {a:1, b?: 1})   &   {b:0 | 1}
  ->        {a: 0, b?: 0} & {b: 1 | 0}  |  {a: 1, b?: 1}  & {b: 1 | 0}
  ->        {a: 0, b: 0}                |  {a: 1, b: 1}
```

So intersecting with `T` not only serves to provide the non-`K` properties, but also gets rid of the unions in the required properties.

To get things working with `Omit`, we can force distribution by adding a dummy extends clause ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)):

```
type DefinedPropD<T, K extends keyof T> =
  T extends any ? Omit<T, K> & Required<Pick<T, K>> : never
type Test = DefinedPropD<{a:0, b?:0} | {a:1, b?: 1}, 'b'>
// {a: 0, b: 0} | {a: 1, b: 1}
```

Unfortunately, a type predicate that uses `DefinedPropD` still fails with the same error :-(

So even though the `DefinedPropO` has issues that can be fixed, TypeScript still cannot infer assignability to `T` for the fixed version. I couldn't find a GitHub issue that exactly matches this case, but it looks like it's just a limitation of type inference. For the `DefinedProp` without `Omit`, assignability is trivially true because of the intersection with `T`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhBmBLAdhAJgBQE4HswB4AVAGigGkoIAPYCZNAZygGsIQd4pCA%20KAXi5QAZFABKEAI4BXRFnT4MiAMbMipMt24AoLWghKANgEM5UJTmQNgUABZGGcJKky4wDAFxQ15SjTqMWNg4ubgAKHE8SQJAPcgBtAF0ASn5eHChEJkcUdGw8bw0tAHoiqAAxHJ1QSFgEHJc8AHkC31p6JlZ2Th5%20KEaAW0RgAt4RcWlZeUUVEe1dfWNTc0trOwc65zy3Rs8W6jaAzuCecMjSTtiyRJS%20NIysjdzXZqjCkqgAUSxcLHdi0oAglBqtAwHI0MojLQAORMEFQfpSKxQABG0HsDEQAHNkEYUQZoMB0kMmGATEZ%20hBaFhYcDwBAAHT-KAswj0qDQ7KbZ4jaH3KDIHDWDHY3H4wnpeHQwjQpnvFks6V88xSAxoVHQFBWIzIYCIKHoKAAdyGNigOvNWBRQywJhAdJqRpsyjNKrVGqgUmQcmMtHVRI5XKeTV5DNCACYAGwAdmjSR0AG8HdBCBBkQJCHgADIQABuEAMADkcFh%20kYDIgAF4QfBBhoEBNGdwABlIKIA-C2AL5QAA%20UEb7gAjG3O1Ah13SNCUdDNFAu8yFVAAHrtxPJrhp6wZ7N5gvF0vlqs1utbZqD1uozvNnv9wcjq%20eCdTmdzhfyhWrqrs0%20uGB7Px2miY5eAzVp-CYHV7XbPpBmGV5RjESQZHBBRlFUBDeE8VB8ywdd4VTdMuF3fMixLMsK2rWtHnrf8L1Hbs%20wHJsHw7J9Jw5V9eHfUoly-eZDBMaBlmRNZfzwBxdlecCgKObowgiLhzjYS5rlSKBiQeJxgzAf8EOZABlPUDAMYEbGgBgKWgCBvhLKB3AAWlCHQtBE4UGExHE8UQCtQEI7cvGk-YIOA%20TQhuXgEy0FkkzczcrEiXoEx7exam0%20sRnnaKBzMCxkX8xKBGS80tPqM9MoXGLcpWeLgEKgcUtK7k8D09RuK0BdvxqTMwBzUiDwo48iFAwRgqAlB4BsqADKgGCEziCgUFC6aEk8AyFoSHtsL3LAAG4dCAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Oblosys and sorry for the missing part. I edited my question and added it for others. I still don't understand the root cause though.

Comment: @fernet No problem! The missing definition definitely makes the question more interesting. One thing is that `Omit` doesn't always behave like you'd expect. For example `Omit<{a:1,b:0} | {a:2,b:0}, 'b'>` is `{a:1 | 2}` instead of `{a:1} | {a:2}` (technically because `Exclude` makes it a non-homomorphic type map, which doesn't distribute). There's more going on though. I'll try and have a closer look in a bit.

Comment: @fernet I thought I found out why `Omit` didn't work and how to fix it, but I had a mistake in a test type and it turned out not to work after all :-( There were some interesting bits in the non-solution though, so I've added it to the answer.